# How to use Entity(EF) and EntityDTO with Contract(Interface)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer, dto, bll

I have an Entity(EF) in DAL, which have generated by Entity Framework.

```
public partial class User : IUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Avatar { get; set; }

    public Guid? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I've created UserDto in BLL

```
public class UserDto : IUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public DepartmentDto Department { get; set; }
    public RoleDto Role { get; set; }
    public Guid? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

To transfer data between DAL and BLL I'm using Contract(Interface)

```
public interface IUser
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Login { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Lastname { get; set; }
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Avatar { get; set; }
}
```

How ,in this case, to transfer navigation fields between DAL and BLL? Like this:

```
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
```

**How better to do:**

**Remove contract(interface) and transfer User(EF) to BLL directly or advice solution to solve this issue. 
Is it right to remove contract(interface) with architecture point of view?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important purpose of creating DTOs is to lose couple your `DomainModel` from your DAL `DTO Model` as I get you. **Then it's totally wrong to couple them again by an interface.**

I advise you to use the same EF model as your DomainModel and use it in your BLL unless you have a large and complex project then it's OK to be more strict to DDD implementation by having real rich DomainModel.

In that case, you should pass your `DomainModel` to your DAL and nothing else and all the mapping should be **inside** of your DAL. You can use then some tool like `AutoMapper` or just manual mapping